# PHP Regex No Consecutive Characters, at least one lower and uppercase, at least one number?

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I've been trying to make a regex that matches a password with the following characteristics:

- At least one vowel
- At least one capital
- At least one number
- And (most important) no consecutive letters or numbers

Example of Invalid passwords

- ThisIsMyyPassword20 - (fails because it repeats 'y' and 's')
- IMissUK20 - (fails because it repeats 's')

Example of Valid passwords

- ThisIsMyPasword20
- IMisUK20
- IdontKnow20
- IidontKnow20 - (Do not fail because 'I' and 'i' are not the same)

BTW: This is the regex I am actually using but DO NOT matches for consecutive characters.

```
regex:/^(?=.*[a-z|A-Z]\1{1})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).+$/
```

Thank you everyone.

Comment: That regex is invalid. You are trying to use a backreference before capturing anything.

Comment: In the title you say you need 1 upper and 1 lower. In the description, you say nothing about a lower, only upper. Both answers below only target upper, not lower. Also, this isn't a freelance service. It is ok to ask for help, but don't offer to pay someone here.

Comment: @chris85, didn't noticed that. Good catch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex for all your requirements:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[aAeEiIoOuU])(?=.*\d)(?:([a-zA-Z\d])(?!\1))+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sQ8iK6/2)

**Here is regex breakup:**

```
^                   # Start
(?=.*[A-Z])         # lookahead to assert a capital letter
(?=.*[aAeEiIoOuU])  # lookahead to assert a vowel
(?=.*\d)            # lookahead to assert a digit
(?:                 # non-capturing group start
   ([a-zA-Z\d])     # match any letter or digit and capture it in group #1
   (?!\1)           # negative lookahead to ensure same char is not repeated
)+                  # non-capturing group end, + ensures 1 ore more of it
$                   # end
```

Comment: It is almost perfect, I need it to NOT accept symbols. Only letters and numbers. Please, fix it and attach your paypal account.

Comment: ok answer is fixed. I am happy to help the community and don't seek payment for the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: If you insist on paying you can contribute the amount to a charity in your neighborhood.

Comment: @anubhava: next time give my paypal account.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?=.*[aeiouAEIOU])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?!.*(.)\1)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

You can use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iJ7bT6/2

Comment: It is accepting symbols, I need to not accept any symbol

Comment: Thank you a lot. @anubhava answered first, but he doesn't want the money, give me ur paypal account and I will transfer. Thank you

Comment: @mkmnstr just accept an answer and buy urself something as a token of gift from SO :)